# How clear elements in CharSequcence in android?

Tags: android

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
   //SecondAt.mBluetoothIO.sendMessage("back");
    }

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int   after){

    // SecondAt.mBluetoothIO.sendMessage("back");
    }

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        if (s.toString().length() == 1) {
            SecondAt.mBluetoothIO.sendMessage("back");
            Toast toast1 = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), s,   Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast1.show();
            }
        else
           {
            //****----"here i need to clear the CharSequence s" ----*****
            }
    }});
```

On the else portion i need to clear the CharSequence s .So that i can read each keys from the keyboard in order to make a bluetooth keyboard.
Someone please help me.

Answer (score 1):

You can try by clearing the `EditText`

```
editText.setText("");
```

Edit 1:

If you want to just clear the value of `CharSequence`:

```
s = "";
```

But this would, won't change the text of `EditText` and thus, if you get next callback of `onTextChanged` listener, previous value would be there. So reset the `EditText` by setting empty `CharSequence` to it.

Edit 2:

```
if (s.toString().length() == 1) { // You are reading the value here.
        SecondAt.mBluetoothIO.sendMessage("back");
        Toast toast1 = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), s,   Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast1.show();
}
else{  // and deleting it from the edittext here.
   s = "";
   editText.setText(s); 
}
```

Comment: @VishnuViswanathan, look at the updated answer. BTW why was it hard though? Are you trying to achieve something else?

Comment: I actually want to read each keys in the soft keyboard in order to build a Bluetooth keyboard for PC.can you help me sir ?

Comment: the app is cashing

Comment: This is not the reason of crash. Anyway can you post the crash report?

Comment: Sir is there i s any other way to read each keys from the soft keyboard to make a Bluetooth keyboard for PC

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
editText.setText(s.subSequence(start,before-1));
```